# Do RDLCs require anything different from the broswer than RDLs?

Tags: reporting-services

So I am new to Microsofts reporting system, and I have been digging thru the differences between RDLs and RDLCs.

The only thing I am currently worried about is if RDLCs require any kind of extra plugin for the brower to work.

Its the Client in RDLC that keeps throwing me, I keep thinking the users local machine will need to do something, but so far it looks like its simply just a report that doesn't need a report server, and so can't be shared (you need to go into the project it was built in to use) but is still built by VS and run by the server and displayed with a reportviewer.

Can someone enlighten me on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In server reports, `ReportViewer` control send the request to Report Server and report create in server. In this type of report, `ReportViewer` only show the report but in Client Reports you don't need to Report Server. For this type of reports, the `ReportViewer` task is that render report.

You don't need anything for viewing client reports on client computers.

Comment: After more searching, that is what I figured, but its nice to be verified.